# What happens to the object after deleting the pointer which previously pointed to it?

Tags: c++, pointers, nodes, doubly-linked-list

This question rises from when I was writing a function to delete the head of a doubly linkedlist, or more specifically I should ask, what happens to the node if we deleted a pointer to it in a linkedlist?

My function is written as:

```
void remHead(){
    Node* tmp = head->next;
    tmp->prev = NULL;
    delete head;
    head = tmp;
}
```

I am asking this question because in my code, I simply just make the second node in the doubly linkedlist prev points to NULL, and delete the pointer pointing to the head, and reassign it to the new head.

**What I omitted(I think) is I didn't make the original head->next points to a NULL**, since I was wondering if we just deleted the head pointer, would its fields(like prev, next) get deleted too? Is that the case? Will it cause any bug since if that's not the case, the original head's next will then point to the new head?

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You didn't delete the pointer. You deleted the object the pointer pointed to.

Comment: Your question implies that you are programming C style. Grab a C++ book and learn about constructor and destructor. Learn about RAII. Learn about smart pointers.

Comment: `delete ptr;` means the object being pointed to is destroyed and the associated memory freed. You don't "delete a pointer" per se in C++, you delete objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, nothing happen, the memory for the head element is getting released when you call free/delete, whatever its content.
The C/C++ do not 'follow' the pointers do perform deep release of resources, (if this was your question), thus nothing to fear here.
BTW, usually, it is the source of leaks as people **should** perform the deep release, but they forget (of thought this was done automatically)

Comment: So, by referring to head element is getting released, you mean the node itself gets deleted as well? So my code is safe in this case?

Comment: when you write delete head; you just release the head element, so yes your code is safe

Answer (score 1):

suppose for clarity you have:

```
class Node {
    /*...*/
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
    /*...*/
};
```

C++ pointers aren't smart pointers (perhaps they're dumb pointers) and `delete`ing a `Node` won't do anything to the objects pointed to by `prev` and `next`.

That is unless you implement a destructor `~Node()` that does something such as `delete next;`.

That will lead to a cascading chain of deletes and you'd have to take care to set `node->next=nullptr` in cases where you were trying to remove a single node.

You'd also hit trouble if you also include `delete prev` because it would result in nodes deleting nodes that had already had `delete` called on them (and are in the process of destruction and calling `delete` on the node in hand.

For this reason linked-list implementations tend not to place ownership in the nodes and implement over-arching ownership in the list:

```
~List(){
   Node*curr{head};
   while(curr!=nullptr){
       auto next{curr->next};
       delete curr;
       curr=next;
   }
}
```

If you do want an object to `delete` another it points to on destruction the modern best practice is to use `std::unique_ptr<>`:

That would be:

```
#include <memory>
/*...*/

class Node {
    /*...*/
    Node* prev;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
    /*...*/
};
```

But as mentioned not usually the best implementation for linked lists if you do any editing (removing/splicing).

Comment: Thanks Persixty! However I think my question is more aligned with something else: will the node gets deleted when I delete its pointer, rather than asking how the next or prev of this node will get deleted in any case. But thanks anyway, your answer does help me understand my question better. The comments above said when I deleted the head pointer( I think it's a pointer since it's Node *head), I actually deleted the head node(the object itself). What's your thought on this? :)

Comment: @Hang They're right. When you call `delete head` you delete the object pointed to by the pointer `head` (if any - i.e. not `nullptr`). You don't `delete` the pointer (`head`). After calling delete `head` is still there to be used. It just points to a now invalid object (if wasn't `nullptr`). Programmers might informally say "you need to `delete head`" but they generally know they don't mean that! This is a fundamental concept in programming - the very important difference between a thing an a reference to a thing (which is itself a thing).

Comment: Thanks for your input Persixty! Then it raised some questions for me: the pointer was not deleted at that time, okay, then would it become a garbage? How could we actually delete the pointer as well? If we didn't delete the pointer, would it possibly cause any memory leak it the "garbage" pointers were accumulating? I appreciate your thoughts :)

Comment: @Hang: The pointer itself will hold a 'garbage' value following deletion. Good practice is to set it to `nullptr` following deletion of the object it references particularly if not in a destructor. The pointer itself (rather than what it references) is part of the `Node` object and the space occupied by the pointer (not what it references) will be recovered when the `Node` object is `delete`d (if allocated using `new`) or when it goes out of scope (if an automatic (AKA local) variable in a function or when the program ends (if file scope (AKA global).

Comment: That's right! Oh yes that's what I actually learned in my class but I didn't fully understand why setting it equal to null after deleting at the time or my class material didn't explain it in this detail. Now I understand it comprehensively! Thanks Persixty! Much appreciated! :D

Answer (score -1):

By default, nothing happens. Default c++ pointers do not track "lost" objects, but there is a solution for this starting from c++11.

There are several smart pointer types declared in `<memory>` [Cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory)

that track "ghost objects" and delete them.